# I was trying to make reflection using custom annotation

Tags: reflection, annotations, illegalaccessexception

i was trying to make reflection using custom annotation  and then this exception appeared. so need help regarding this issue,thanks in advance

```
public class AnnotationTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
             Cat mycat = new Cat("zeus", 10);
             
            for(Method method:mycat.getClass().getDeclaredMethods())
                
                if(method.isAnnotationPresent(RunImmediately.class)){
                    
                    method.invoke(mycat);
                }
    }

}
```

method.invoke(mycat);
throw illegalaccess exception and i dont know why and how can i fix this

unreported exception java.lang.IllegalAccessException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: The [method `invoke`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object...)) declares “throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException” so you have to either, use `try … catch …` to catch and handle those exceptions or alter your `main` method to declare to potentially throw those exceptions too.

Comment: See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html